# Having problem displaying dataframe with streamlit

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, streamlit

```
data_to_graph = combined_summary_df.unstack(level=1, fill_value=0)

with st.expander("Where to test everything related to graph"):
    st.write(data_to_graph)
```

"I am new to Streamlit. I would like to impress my superior with it. Any help, Please!!!

The error below has been returned to me everytime I used the chunk of code above to display my dataframe in Streamlit:"

*

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 6 at JSON.parse
> () at
> http://localhost:8501/static/js/main.970d3503.chunk.js:2:17823 at
> Array.map () at Function.value
> (http://localhost:8501/static/js/main.970d3503.chunk.js:2:17792) at
> new e (http://localhost:8501/static/js/main.970d3503.chunk.js:2:10780)
> at e.get
> (http://localhost:8501/static/js/main.970d3503.chunk.js:2:428662) at
> sn (http://localhost:8501/static/js/main.970d3503.chunk.js:2:461308)
> at ia (http://localhost:8501/static/js/5.26b8f29c.chunk.js:2:3245026)
> at Gl (http://localhost:8501/static/js/5.26b8f29c.chunk.js:2:3297484)
> at Pc (http://localhost:8501/static/js/5.26b8f29c.chunk.js:2:3284658)

- 

Comment: What is combined_summary_df? At what line does the error refers to?

Comment: combined_summary_df is a multiindex dataframe and the error as you can see above is encountered at position 6.

Comment: Could you post a sample minimal dataframe where you have an issue?

Comment: It's a little tricky there. The data are confidential. But you can take any multiindex dataframe you want and try to unstack it using the default values for the parameters and try to display it in streamlit using table, dataframe or write to reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample multi-indexed frame, streamlit is ok. Can you try that?

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st 


index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('one', 'a'), ('one', 'b'),
                                   ('two', 'a'), ('two', 'b')])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=index)

st.write('##### Multiindex df')
st.table(df)

u1 = df.unstack(level=1)
st.write('##### unstack level=1')
st.table(u1)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your precious help, I already tried that and It displays it easily. But it doesn't apply to my case. Do you think that streamlit can be struggling with the number of columns? Because I have 116 columns. Thank you!

Comment: You can change the 2 to 200 in the example and streamlit is ok with it.